# Remove "On Server-Name" from network printers

Tags: windows-8, printer, network-printer

I'd like to remove the on ServerName from network printers. The name becomes rather long when it is fully qualified IE "Color Printer on someserver.someverylongdomain.local" instead of just "Color Printer". This is annoying one of our users who attempts to select if from a list.

I am looking for a way to disable the on Server Name such as below removing the on DCC-IND-01 if anyone has any advice.

[image: Network Printer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it does not seem possible.